# Angular dynamic pages

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a portfolio site in Angular JS that should work like this:

**Portfolio listing page**
- Listing of projects (with title + technology) from a JSON file.
- Show more / less
- Show (filter technology)

**Portfolio detail page**
- New page with:
     - visual
     - description
     - visit website

- Go to next/previous detail page
- A view below with similar projects (technology), except current one

The listing page is working but I can't figure out how to make dynamic pages for the detail pages. Is it even possible to do so? So when a user click's on a thumbnail, it should show a page with the additional information from the json file. And how can I implement 'next/previous'?

Any directions or tutorials would be awesome!

Comment: Can you provide a sample image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a page with thumbs, generated by Angular (JSON), when you click on one, I want a new page with additional information about the project.

Comment: @saerts you should looking for **routing** - https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 - please make https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial tutorial - it will help you to understand concept of mulitpe views